# Why my browser shows blank page when I run express server (React.js)?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I'm new to React. I want to deploy my react project to Heroku. To do that I implemented a simple express server. But nothing renders on my browser at `localhost:3000` when I run the server with `node server/server.js`. Am I missing something obvious here?

My project structure:

[image: My project structure]

server.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

// console.log that your server is up and running
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));

// create a GET route
app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
  res.send(res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../src/index.html')));
});
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />

    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `index.html` in `src`. With `create-react-app` the file `index.html` it would be put into `build` when command `npm run build` is executed. It generates an `index.html` with urls to the JS/CSS dynamically injected. One option is you you could consider putting the React application into `public`, then target `index.html` of the `build` folder generated by `npm run build`:

```
// create a GET route
app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
  // update this path to match how you set up express to serve static and where your build is output to
  res.send(res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'path', 'to', 'build', 'index.html')));
});
```

Also you need to make sure you have [static file serving](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) set up for express:

```
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

`static` can also target multiple directories in case you don't want to nest your react project too deeply:

```
app.use(express.static('public'))
app.use(express.static('build'))
```

It's fairly common to have static assets in `public` such as images, but regardless of the structure you choose, you need to specify a path for static assets including the HTML, CSS, and JS generated by `create-react-app` build.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I updated inside of my get function with `res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '..','build', 'index.html'))` to target the `index.html` that is generated by `npm run build` like you said. I also added the static file serving. However I am confused with this part of your answer: "One option is you you could consider putting the React application into `public`" 
Am I supposed to carry everything (my react components, index.js etc...) from my `src` folder to `public` folder before running `npm run build`?

Comment: Sure, let me clarify. `build/index.html` generated by `npm run build` should be contained in a path specific by express `static` so that it can effectively be served. You'll need to decide which directories you specify as static resource paths and determine the ideal location for directory `build`.